# PFObject unable to be cast to custom subclass

Tags: swift, casting, parse-platform

This code was working fine before the recent update to the swift compiler update.  I have corrected all the obvious errors, but for some reason when I run the app now it crashes in the `for in loop` when trying to cast `[AnyObject]` to my custom `Memory` class.

The log and error shows as follows:

```
Has connectivity
Successfully retrieved 8 memories.
current memory: <Memories: 0x170120960, objectId: AO3EvPFob4, localId: (null)> {
ACL = "<PFACL: 0x174047e30>";
Date = "3915-04-08 05:00:00 +0000";
Guests = 4;
Title = test4;
}
Could not cast value of type 'PFObject' (0x100130bc0) to 'MemoryVault.Memory' (0x10012fa00).
```

So I know I'm retrieving 8 correct memories from Parse, and the current memory is correct...it just wont cast it.

The code:

```
    if (NetworkValidator.hasConnectivity()){ // Has internet connectivity
        println("Has connectivity")
        Memory.memoryQuery().findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                // The find succeeded.
                 println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) memories.")

                Memory.unpinAllInBackground(self.memories, block: {
                    (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                    // Clear current list
                    self.memories = [Memory]()

                    // Do something with the found objects
                    for memory in objects! {
                        println("current memory: \(memory)")
                        let currentMemory: Memory = memory as! Memory

                        // Save to localDataStore
                        currentMemory.pinInBackground()
                        println("\(currentMemory.memoryTitle) from Parse")

                        // Append to current
                        self.memories.append(currentMemory)
                    }
                })

                // Notify tableView to reload data
                self.memoriesTableView.reloadData()
            } else {

                // Log details of the failure
                println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

this one kept me busy some hours - Parse-Documentation mentions:

> Strongly-typed subclasses of PFObject must conform to the PFSubclassing protocol and must call before [Parse setApplicationId:clientKey:] is called."

By calling **MyParseClass.registerSubclass()** in **AppDelegate** I got my issues fixed!

Comment: WOW, thanks! I've just added a new model and spent hours trying to figure this out. I totally forgot about my function in AppDelegate where I have to call `registerSubclass` on each of my models to avoid this issue. I hope we get rid of this hacky workaround soon!

Comment: Do I need to add `PFSubclassing` to the class definition of the subclasses?