# How do I retrieve an array of a custom subclass of PFObjects stored under the PFUser.currentUser()

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm struggling with retrieving an array of PFObjects that I stored on the PFUser.currentUser()

I have a custom subclass of PFObject: UNUser

Here's how I save the array of [UNUser] called favoriteDrivers:

```
if let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser() {
  currentUser["favoriteDrivers"] = favoriteDrivers
  currentUser.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (succes: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if succes {
    }
  })
}
```

If I retrieve the entry like this:

```
if let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser() {
    var objects = currentUser["favoriteDrivers"]
```

println(objects) shows this in the console (the array in this trial has just one entry):

```
Optional(("<UNUser: 0x174138920, objectId: mEgJALLLA9, localId: (null)> {\n}"))
```

What is the best way to now fetch the referred to PFObjects and store them in an array of UNUser?

This is what I tried:

```
  var relation = currentUser.relationForKey("favoriteDrivers")
    relation.query()!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{ ( objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
      if error == nil {
        let favoriteDrivers = objects as? [UNUser]
```

Comment: Is it an array or a relation? They're different and don't work interchangeably...

Comment: I store it as an array

Comment: Then you need to read it as an array. Did you try that?

Comment: I did, but to no avail

Comment: The panel on the parse website shows this: `[{"__type":"Pointer","className":"UNUser","objectId":"mEgJALKLA9"}]`

Answer (score 2):

You're setting an array so you need to read an array, not a relation.

Your array is actually an array of pointers, which is exactly what you want, but you do need to ensure that you have all of the data for those pointers as by default (and as you can see in your log) you only get the class type and object ids.

To do that, get the array and then call `fetchAllIfNeededInBackground:block:` with the array. That will update any of the objects in the array that need it with the current data from the server. This is kind of like your relation query...

Comment: Thanks Wain. I'm afraid I'm still not there. I did get the objects themselves but can't seem to downcast to my custom PFObject subclass UNUser, I get objects but not favoriteDrivers in the following snippet, although the array was stored as an array of [UNUser]: `        PFObject.fetchAllIfNeededInBackground(objects, block: { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
          if error == nil {
            println(objects)
            if let favoriteDrivers = objects as? [UNUser]{
              println(favoriteDrivers)`

Comment: Compilation issue or it just never gets inside the `if` statement?

Comment: It never gets inside the `if` statement

Comment: How have you defined `UNUser` in the code then, because the log looks ok

Comment: `class UNUser: PFObject, PFSubclassing, Printable {
  
  override class func initialize() {
    var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken) {
      self.registerSubclass()
    }
  }
  
  static func parseClassName() -> String {
    return "UNUser"
  }`

Comment: Not sure then, I don't write swift currently so it looks ok to me. What do you get when you log the `objects` ?

Comment: `Optional([<UNUser: 0x17412fd20, objectId: epd0NFkBc1, localId: (null)> {
    ACL = "<PFACL: 0x17004f6f0>";
    email = "cba.nospam@me.com";
    name = 5me;
}, <UNUser: 0x17412fdc0, objectId: rtlAu09d1L, localId: (null)> {
    ACL = "<PFACL: 0x17004b820>";
    email = "abc.nospam@icloud.com";
    name = 6cloud;
}])`

Comment: Could it have to do with the fact that the subclass needs to registered before setApplicationID is called as per: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29672170/4726630) If I try this through `UNUser.initialize()`, my app crashes with the message: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Key "name" has no data.  Call fetchIfNeeded before getting its value.`

Comment: the log looks good, they are the correct class type, not sure why the exception

Comment: Many thanks Wain for your trouble. I will just go ahead and manually cast it to my custom subclass UNUser by looping through the array of PFObjects